# k3b does not recognize author/title/time by ripping Audio-CD by minimal install

Tags: software-installation, cd, k3b, musicbrainz

I have on two discs fresh installed a vanilla Ubuntu 22.04 and another one upgraded to 22.04 an 20.04 minimal install. At Ubuntu 22.04 I have installed `k3b` and when I rip Audio-CD, database is queried and I have recognized Author/Title/Time of ripped Audio-CD. Against it, at minimal 22.04 I have not this recognition. On minimal install I have installed `k3b` as follows:

```
root@jammy:~# apt install k3b --install-recommends --install-suggests 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree... Done 
Reading state information... Done 
The following additional packages will be installed: 
 aglfn bwidget cdck cdparanoia cdrdao cdrkit-doc cdrskin dvd+rw-tools flac 
 genisoimage gnuplot gnuplot-data gnuplot-doc gnuplot-qt growisofs icedax jigit
 k3b-data k3b-extrathemes k3b-i18n kde-config-cddb libappimage0 
 libaudio-scrobbler-perl libaudiofile1 libauthen-ntlm-perl libauthen-sasl-perl 
 libburn4 libbusiness-isbn-data-perl libbusiness-isbn-perl 
 libbytes-random-secure-perl libclone-perl libconfig-inifiles-perl 
 libcrypt-random-seed-perl libcrypt-ssleay-perl libdata-dump-perl 
 libdigest-hmac-perl libencode-locale-perl libfile-listing-perl libflac++6v5 
 libfont-afm-perl libgd-barcode-perl libgd-perl libgssapi-perl 
 libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl 
 libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl 
 libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libio-html-perl 
 libio-socket-ssl-perl libiso9660-11 libisoburn1 libisofs6 libjte2 libk3b7 
 libk3b7-extracodecs libkf5attica5 libkf5auth5 libkf5cddb5 
 libkf5filemetadata-bin libkf5filemetadata-data libkf5filemetadata3 
 libkf5kcmutils-data libkf5kcmutils5 libkf5kiofilewidgets5 libkf5newstuff-data 
 libkf5newstuff5 libkf5newstuffcore5 libkf5notifyconfig-data 
 libkf5notifyconfig5 libkf5syndication5abi1 liblua5.4-0 liblwp-mediatypes-perl 
 liblwp-protocol-https-perl libmailtools-perl libmath-random-isaac-perl 
 libmath-random-isaac-xs-perl libmusicbrainz5cc2v5 libneon27-gnutls 
 libnet-http-perl libnet-smtp-ssl-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libopencore-amrnb0 
 libopencore-amrwb0 libperl4-corelibs-perl libqt5quickwidgets5 libsox-fmt-all 
 libsox-fmt-alsa libsox-fmt-ao libsox-fmt-base libsox-fmt-mp3 libsox-fmt-oss 
 libsox-fmt-pulse libsox3 libsquashfuse0 libsub-name-perl libtcl8.6 
 libtimedate-perl libtk8.6 libtry-tiny-perl liburi-perl libvcdinfo0 libwww-perl 
 libwww-robotrules-perl libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 mpg321 
 normalize-audio perl-openssl-defaults qml-module-org-kde-newstuff sox tcl 
 tcl-tclreadline tcl8.6 tk tk8.6 vcdimager vorbis-tools wodim xorriso 
 xorriso-tcltk 
Suggested packages: 
 movixmaker-2
The following NEW packages will be installed: 
 aglfn bwidget cdck cdparanoia cdrdao cdrkit-doc cdrskin dvd+rw-tools flac 
 genisoimage gnuplot gnuplot-data gnuplot-doc gnuplot-qt growisofs icedax jigit 
 k3b k3b-data k3b-extrathemes k3b-i18n kde-config-cddb libappimage0 
 libaudio-scrobbler-perl libaudiofile1 libauthen-ntlm-perl libauthen-sasl-perl 
 libburn4 libbusiness-isbn-data-perl libbusiness-isbn-perl 
 libbytes-random-secure-perl libclone-perl libconfig-inifiles-perl 
 libcrypt-random-seed-perl libcrypt-ssleay-perl libdata-dump-perl 
 libdigest-hmac-perl libencode-locale-perl libfile-listing-perl libflac++6v5 
 libfont-afm-perl libgd-barcode-perl libgd-perl libgssapi-perl 
 libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl 
 libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl 
 libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libio-html-perl 
 libio-socket-ssl-perl libiso9660-11 libisoburn1 libisofs6 libjte2 libk3b7 
 libk3b7-extracodecs libkf5attica5 libkf5auth5 libkf5cddb5 
 libkf5filemetadata-bin libkf5filemetadata-data libkf5filemetadata3 
 libkf5kcmutils-data libkf5kcmutils5 libkf5kiofilewidgets5 libkf5newstuff-data 
 libkf5newstuff5 libkf5newstuffcore5 libkf5notifyconfig-data 
 libkf5notifyconfig5 libkf5syndication5abi1 liblua5.4-0 liblwp-mediatypes-perl 
 liblwp-protocol-https-perl libmailtools-perl libmath-random-isaac-perl 
 libmath-random-isaac-xs-perl libmusicbrainz5cc2v5 libneon27-gnutls 
 libnet-http-perl libnet-smtp-ssl-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libopencore-amrnb0 
 libopencore-amrwb0 libperl4-corelibs-perl libqt5quickwidgets5 libsox-fmt-all 
 libsox-fmt-alsa libsox-fmt-ao libsox-fmt-base libsox-fmt-mp3 libsox-fmt-oss 
 libsox-fmt-pulse libsox3 libsquashfuse0 libsub-name-perl libtcl8.6 
 libtimedate-perl libtk8.6 libtry-tiny-perl liburi-perl libvcdinfo0 libwww-perl 
 libwww-robotrules-perl libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 mpg321 
 normalize-audio perl-openssl-defaults qml-module-org-kde-newstuff sox tcl 
 tcl-tclreadline tcl8.6 tk tk8.6 vcdimager vorbis-tools wodim xorriso 
 xorriso-tcltk 
0 upgraded, 127 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
Need to get 32,8 MB of archives. 
After this operation, 120 MB of additional disk space will be used. 
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
```

Installed version of `k3b`:

```
~$ k3b -v
k3b 21.12.3
```

Both `ssd`'s I start at same hardware, but the effect, as I wrote, is different.
What would you advise to achieve the desired result?

Comment: I guess the best you can do just now is to reach out to the developer with your concerns -  https://www.kde.org/applications/multimedia/k3b/

Comment: I guess this is Ubuntu issue, just a difference in installed packages or something like that.

Comment: 3rd party software is not maintained by Canonical. This is a matter to raise with the developer.